# mongoose search for userid inside an array and if found, delete it along with duplicates. how?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So someone hits the like button. It'll call this function below. I need it to not push the same user twice. Also if the like button is pressed again it'll act as a dislike or remove like, so it should delete the user from this array of likes. How do I do that? This is what I have so far

```
chapterController.likeChapter = function (req, res) {
    var userId = req.body.by;
    var chapterId = req.body.chapterId;



        Chapter.findOne({
      _id: chapterId


    }, function(err, chap){

      if(chap.likes.indexOf(userId) !== -1){
          chap.likes.pull(userId);

      }else{
        chap.likes.addToSet(userId);
      }
        chap.save();
    })





      Chapter.findByIdAndUpdate(chapterId, {
      $push: {
        likes: userId
      }
     }, {}, function(err, obj) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        Chapter.find({_id: chapterId}).then(function (chapter) {
            var chapter = chapter;
            Comment.find({chapterId: chapterId}).then(function(data){
                return res.send({ commentList : data, user: req.user, chapter: chapter});
                //console.log(chapter);
            });

         })

      }
    });
  };
```

UPDATE: it does most of what I want so far with what I have posted. I need it to delete all duplicates as well. Not just one.

Answer (score 0):

I dont exactly know your data model but inside the callback of Chapter.findByIdAndUpdate you can map the user id's like this;

```
obj.userid.map((userIdFromDb) => {
 if(userIdFromDb !== userId) {
    do something...
  }
})
```

But i higly suggest you that, if you have any growing data by time, do not use mongodb. You can use relational database and mongo would hold for you statics in this case.

Answer (score 0):

> I need it to not push the same user twice.

Use [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) instead of [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/push/).

```
Chapter.findByIdAndUpdate(chapterId, {
  $addToSet: {
    likes: userId
  }
 }, ...
```

> Also if the like button is pressed again it'll act as a dislike or remove like, so it should delete the user from this array of likes.

Use the [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator in an update like the one you have for the `$push` case:

```
Chapter.findByIdAndUpdate(chapterId, {
  $pull: {
    likes: userId
  }
 } ...
```